# Get date numerical and separate?

Tags: php, functions, date, date-time

I need to work with date function but I want to get day and month numerical and separate and pass it to a function.

For example, I want work for this function.

```
function(day,month)
```

How can I get date of today on pass it to a function aside?

Comment: This question belongs on [so] as it has no relevance to Wordpress ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you (tried it and it works):

```
date('m', strtotime('0 month'));
date('d', strtotime('0 day'));
```

[Here is a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733636/trying-to-get-the-number-of-the-month-before-of-the-current-month) on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following functions:

```
time ();
```

return The time by seconds

```
date();
```

y- Year
m- Month
d- Day

h- Hours
i- Minute
s- Second

for ex:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```